# “Exception in thread ”main“ java.lang.StackOverflowError” in Quick sort for sorted, reversed and Identical data of size greater than 10000

Tags: java, algorithm, stack, out-of-memory

I have tried to implement quick sort algorithm for all the inputs of different data size and formats. The basic code for partition is:

```
public static void QuickSortAlgorithm(int[] array) {
    QuickSort(array, 0, array.length-1);
}

public static void QuickSort(int[] A, int p, int r) {
    if (p < r) {
        int q = Partition(A, p, r);
        QuickSort(A, p, q - 1);
        QuickSort(A, q + 1, r);
    }
}

public static int Partition(int[] A, int p, int r) {
    int x = A[r];
    int i = p - 1;
    for (int j = p; j <= r - 1; j++) {
        if (A[j] <= x) {
            i = i + 1;
            int temp1;
            temp1 = A[i];
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = temp1;
        }
    }
    int temp2;
    temp2 = A[i + 1];
    A[i + 1] = A[r];
    A[r] = temp2;

    return i + 1;

}
```

}

But, it works fine for random data of size up to 80,000. But in case of sorted and reversed data it throws error "“Exception in thread ”main“ java.lang.StackOverflowError”. I have tried to run it through command line, passing file name as an argument.

```
java -Xss1m QuickSortProgram  sorted_40000.txt
```

But still it throws error. How to solve it? I need to run the program via command line. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you're getting into infinite recursion in your main function. It's hard to tell if you don't post the entire code.

Comment: You dont need to increase stack size check your loops and recursive calls, as far as you dont modify j parameter your loop doesnt seem to be reason of that

Comment: @Catalin, it seems unlikely that he has an infinite recursion only for inputs larger than a certain size.  You don't anyway need *infinite* recursion to produce a stack overflow, only *deep enough* recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted and reverse-sorted data are troublesome cases for your particular pivot-selection approach of choosing the last element of the starting partition.  You will always get zero elements in one of the sub-partitions (supposing that you don't attribute the pivot itself to either one).  If you employ a naive implementation of the overall sort, then that means you will recurse to a depth equal to the number of elements to be sorted, and that sets you up for running out of stack space.

Reverse-sorted is in fact a worst case, for even if you solve the recursion depth problem, you'll still get quadratic performance in the size of the input.

There are several things you could do.  The first is to fix the overall sort so that it is not subject to this kind of problem at all.  You can do this by taking a hybrid iterative / recursive approach, wherein the larger of each pair of sub-partitions is sorted without recursing.  This reliably limits the recursion depth to at most log<sub>2</sub>(*n*) for inputs of size *n*.  Example:

```
static void quickSort(int[] a, int p, int r) {
    while (r - p > 1) {
        int q = Partition(a, p, r);

        if (q - p <= (r - p) / 2) {
            // the left-hand partition is smaller; sort it recursively
            quickSort(a, p, q - 1);
            // update p so as to sort the right-hand partition iteratively
            p = q + 1;
        } else {
            // the right-hand partition is smaller; sort it recursively
            quickSort(a, q + 1, r);
            // update r so as to sort the left-hand partition iteratively
            r = q - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

You could additionally consider a more advanced pivot selection algorithm.  Median-of-three would improve behavior in the cases where the input is initially sorted or reverse-sorted, though there are median-of-three killer inputs that can still elicit quadratic behavior.  Alternatively, random pivot selection affords no reliable killer inputs, and although behavior is only *probabilistically* O(n log(n)), the chances of significant differences from that scaling rule become vanishingly small as the size of the input increases.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually normal: Quicksort (using the first or last element as pivot as you do) runs in time O(n * log n) in average, but O(n^2) when the data is already sorted. The number of recursive calls is usually O(log n), but O(n) when it's already sorted.

So you just have cases where it takes a lot of time, because of a lot of recursive calls, so you get a stack overflow... You'll get the same error if you try using it on a randomly ordered but much bigger (say 2^40000, I advise you not to do that ;) ) dataset.

If you still need to order your sorted data, you should use another choice for pivot. A simple solution is to take a random one, but it does not *ensure* that you will *never* get O(n) recursive calls. If you want to be sure of that, you should use more clever methods, such as those proposed by John Bollinger .

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: Even a random pivot choice affords a *chance* of recursing to O(n) depth.  To be sure, it's a miniscule chance for inputs large enough to matter, but you don't need to leave it to chance at all.  It is possible to *ensure* that the recursion depth is O(log n).